# How to set owner role in this like we set owner to solidity?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, authority, owner, immutable-owner

"In my contract, I require the implementation of an owner role, creating what is commonly known as an 'ownable' contract pattern. This entails the inclusion of three key functions within my contract:

1. `initialize_owner`: This function is called once during the contract's initialization. The caller of this function becomes the initial owner.
2. `set_new_owner`: Only the initial owner can call this function, and it allows the setting of a new owner by providing a new public key.
3. `renounce_ownership`: Only the current owner can invoke this function, resulting in the owner being set to the default address '11111111111111111111111111111111', effectively renouncing ownership.

Additionally, I need a mechanism to retrieve the owner's address within the code, facilitating validation checks to determine if a particular method is being called by the admin.

Could you please provide examples or solutions for implementing these requirements?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Solidity contracts, Solana programs are stateless. Accounts hold the state of solana programs. Hence, the concept of "ownership" is valid only for accounts not for programs itself.

By default `init` sets the owner field of the created account to the currently executing program. You must add the owner constraint to specify a different program owner.

Here's a simple example:

```
#[program]
pub mod anchor_example {
    use anchor_lang::solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult;

    use super::*;
    pub fn create_pool(ctx: Context<CreatePool>) -> ProgramResult {
        let pool = &mut ctx.accounts.pool_account;
        pool.id = 1;
        pool.owner = *ctx.accounts.user.key;
        Ok(())
    }
 
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreatePool<'info> {
   #[account(init, payer = user, owner = user.key(), space = 8 + 40 )]
    pub pool_account: Account<'info, Pool>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Pool {
    pub id: u64,
}
```